# Fork process in ruby and write to the same file

Tags: ruby, file, process, subprocess, fork

Is there a way to make different processes spawned by fork write to the same file during run time?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't it "just work"?

Comment: No, I couldn't manage to get it working. I initialized a new file and inside the new file block, I have the fork block, and when I try to append new lines to the file it doesn't write anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fork`ed processes will get a copy of the original file descriptor, so assuming the parent held a file handle before it `fork`ed, it'll "just work" with some care (much like multiple processes sharing a file, though note in the `fork` case, the underlying kernel descriptor is identical, so your processes will share things like the current offset). If `test.rb` contains

```
require 'tmpdir'

filename = Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname('/tmp/', '')
puts filename

file = File.open(filename, 'w')

file.write("Pre-fork\n")
file.flush

pid = fork

file.write(pid ? "In parent\n" : "In child\n")

file.close
```

then `cat $(ruby ./test.rb)` will contain

```
Pre-fork
In parent
In child
```

Note I'm flushing the file before I fork to ensure that we don't see two `Pre-fork`s due to IO buffering. Depending on the type of "sharing" you want, this may be sufficient.